# hsqldb and jdk8 compatibility

Tags: java, maven, version, hsqldb

I try to use org.hsqldb.hsqldb in my Maven project. The requirement of the client is to use Java 8. The current version of org.hsqldb.hsqldb is 2.6.1, which doesn't seem to work with Java 8. How can I observe the version of HSQLDB that compiles with Java 8?

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I observe the version"? Is your problem determining correct hsqldb version (compatible with jdk 1.8) or importing that version in maven?

Comment: "Latest version 2.6.1 works with JDK 8 and above" - what precisely is your problem?

Comment: What does this mean: ` it seems it does not work with Java 1.8.` ?

Comment: Gyro Gearless, khmarbaise, using 2.6.1 gives me an error, I haven't written it, but from the definition, I suspect that 2.6.1 does not work well with JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First read the [release notes for hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/changelist_2_0.txt):

```
21 March 2021 - version 2.6.0
-- version 2.6.0 jar requires JRE 11 or later - tested up to Java 16 RC
-- version 2.6.0 alternative jar requires JRE 8 or later
```

The documentation clearly states that 2.6.0 needs an alternative jar to work with jdk8.

Inpect the [hsqldb maven repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.6.1/) to verify that there is an alternative jar provided for jdk8: hsqldb-2.6.1-jdk8.jar

To import it with maven, you need to use a **classifier**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <classifier>jdk8</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This answer helped me. See also https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1644/ and https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/feature-requests/359/ which point out that you need the "classifier". It can be used with version 2.7.x, too.